# Jenkins giving "The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing." error while Running cypress Test

Tags: cypress

Hi I am Trying to run cypress test through Jenkins and am getting the test form my local m/c not form github and am Executing windows batch command 
"./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec "cypress\integration\SignUpTestCases\NewUserSignUp.spec.js" in Bulid configuration.

and i am getting this error

C:\Users\akash\CypressAutomation>./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec "cypress\integration\SignUpTestCases\NewUserSignUp.spec.js" 
The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing.

We expected the binary to be installed here: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.4.1\Cypress\Cypress.exe

Reasons it may be missing:

- You're caching 'node_modules' but are not caching this path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache
- You ran 'npm install' at an earlier build step but did not persist: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache

Properly caching the binary will fix this error and avoid downloading and unzipping Cypress.

Alternatively, you can run 'cypress install' to download the binary again.

https://on.cypress.io/not-installed-ci-error

WHat is the problem here .....or pls tell me about cypress configuration with Jenkins!!!!

Comment: Did you resolve your problem ? I'm facing the same thing now.

Comment: Hi 
am still facing same problem but not found any solution yet....

Comment: If you're using Docker use Docker image with Cypress preinstalled with all its dependencies. I made it work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Please set up environment variable CYPRESS_RUN_BINARY and its value should be your cypress runner location. （the runner defauly localtion is ~/AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache）
the variable setting:
Name: CYPRESS_RUN_BINARY
Value:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.8.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe

Or you can add the command in the jenkins job:
set CYPRESS_RUN_BINARY=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.8.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe before run the cypress cases.

Comment: Anyone got the solution for this?

Comment: @vaibhavv did you get solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

Your problem probably exists because you have `node_modules` added to your git repository.

1. Remove node_modules folder from your repository
2. add node_modules to `.gitignore` file.
3. commit changes, push them and try again.